# Is there a way to `goog.provide` something without using the global object?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, google-closure-library

Using the global object for this has been problematic for me. Here is a simple example that illustrates my problem:

In `a.js`:

```
goog.provide('app.a');

goog.require('app.b');

app.a = function () {
    return [
        app.b('Hey, there!'),
        app.c('yo')
    ];
};
```

Note in the above file, I am using `app.c` without explicitly requiring it.

In `b.js`:

```
goog.provide('app.b');

goog.require('app.c');

app.b = function (msg) {
    return app.c('b ' + msg);
};
```

In `c.js`:

```
goog.provide('app.c');

app.c = function (msg) {
    return { msg: msg };
};
```

I can run this through closurebuilder and it will run just fine. It will also run without error in the browser. But I don't like how `app.c` is usable without being explicitly required.

The best solution I can think of is if each file could somehow use its own copy of the `app` global variable that is built up from the `goog.require` calls. This would result in runtime errors when you try to use something that wasn't `require`d. Not sure if this is possible.

Is there a way to do what I described, or is there some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to put a require for app.c in app.a, and that is a best practice but yeah it won't catch it if you don't because of the way requirements are harvested by the compiler. It would throw an error if you removed the app.b requirement, just one of the many, many, many quirks of closure land.